# Rails Redirect depending on logged in status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a contact form in my rails app. Right now it just redirects to the home page no matter what. I would like to redirect to the user_path if the user is logged in and the homepage if they are not.. How would i do this?

*using devise

contact_controller

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(user_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 6):

you can just redirect elsewhere if they are logged in:

```
if current_user
    redirect_to(user_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
else
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

This is assuming your `current_xxx` is setup as "`user`"

Comment: right but how would i tag that on to my current if/else (listed above)

Comment: You don't tack it on; you include it inside of your current if-else. Just replace your redirect_to line with the if-else coneybeare gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `user_signed_in?` helper

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  if @message.valid?
    NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to user_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent."
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
    render :new
  end
end
```